# AngularJS best practices directory structure

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular to follow best practices outlined here https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XXMvReO8-Awi1EZXAXS4PzDzdNvV6pGcuaF4Q9821Es/pub

I'm now introducing a new CRUD player feature of my application and was wondering where to best put them.

I've put them under player folder under app directory then created a new file called `player.controller.js`

Is this the right approach?

How do we define the scope for directory and file?

Comment: There's a nice guideline [here](https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide) to structure your angularjs app.

Comment: @VahidND thanks for this. However where can I put player controller?